# Display project status using HTML table and CSS3

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I want to track status of a few of my projects like the image below:
[image: Progress bar]

Activity 1/2/3 will have some data fetched from a data source and will contain startdate and enddate.

The table I am using is formatted with bootstrap. The progress bar code (css, html, javascript) is from the stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36760716/html5-css3-layout-to-show-tasks-running-status) (Thanks for the excellent post and answer)

However I am not able to combine both the table and css from post to show progress bar as per my data received. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Here is what I tried [Fiddle Code](https://jsfiddle.net/10h3k5gm/)

```js
$(function() {
  $('.progress>div').each(function() {
    $(this).css('width', $(this).data('progress'));
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: white;
}

.project {
  width: 1000px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.project>div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 -5px 0 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.task {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  border: .4em solid #E4E4E7;
  background: #E4E4E7;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.progress {
  width: calc( 50% - 3em);
  height: .6em;
  padding: .2em 0;
  background: #E4E4E7;
  position: relative;
}

.progress>div {
  height: .2em;
  left: -.4em;
  right: -.4em;
  position: absolute;
}

.pending {
  background: #F8AC59;
}

.running {
  background: #1C84C6;
}

.passed {
  background: #1AB394;
}

.failed {
  background: #ED5565;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Activity</th>
      <th colspan="4" class="text-center">Jan-17</th>
      <th colspan="4" class="text-center">Feb-17</th>
      <th colspan="4" class="text-center">Mar-17</th>
      <th colspan="4" class="text-center">Apr-17</th>
      <th colspan="4" class="text-center">May-17</th>
      <th colspan="4" class="text-center">June-17</th>
      <th colspan="4" class="text-center">July-17</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Activity 1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <div class="task passed" title="Task completed"></div>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Activity 2</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Activity 3</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you share what you tried? any fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

If your table cells will always be the same width, this is something you could do. It's not perfect, but gives you an idea on how to get what you are asking for.

The only change to the HTML, is I added `data-length="<NUMBER>"` on the task divs. The number is how many table columns the task will span.

```js
$(function () {
  $('.progress > div').each(function () {
    $(this).css('width', $(this).data('progress'));
  });
});
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background: white;
}

/*Start New Added Styles*/

/*Needed for the absolute positioned bars.*/
td {
    position: relative;
}

/*Needed to make the table columns the same size.*/
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}

/*Center the left side circle in the table cell.*/
div[data-length] {
    margin-left: 25%;
}

/*The spanning bar.*/
div[data-length]:before {
    content: " ";
    z-index: -1;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 8px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0,-50%);
}

/*The circle at the end of the spanning bar.*/
div[data-length]:after {
    content: " ";
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    transform: translate(0,-50%);
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    border: .4em solid #E4E4E7;
    background: #E4E4E7;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

/*Passed colour styles for the spanning bar.*/
div.passed[data-length]:before {
    background: #1AB394;
    border-top: 2px solid #E4E4E7;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #E4E4E7;
}

/*Passed colour styles for the circle at the end of the spanning bar.*/
div.passed[data-length]:after {
    background: #1AB394;
}

/*The bar that will span 10 table columns.*/
div[data-length='10']:before {
    width: calc(900% + 1em);
}

/*The circle at the end of the 10 spanning bar.*/
div[data-length='10']:after {
    left: calc(900% + 2em);
}

/*The bar that will span 3 table columns.*/
div[data-length='3']:before {
    width: calc(200% + 1em);
}

/*The circle at the end of the 3 spanning bar.*/
div[data-length='3']:after {
    left: calc(200% + 2em);
}

/*End New Added Styles*/

.project {
    width: 1000px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.project > div {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 -5px 0 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.task {
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    border: .4em solid #E4E4E7;
    background: #E4E4E7;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.progress {
    width: calc(50% - 3em);
    height: .6em;
    padding: .2em 0;
    background: #E4E4E7;
    position: relative;
}

.progress > div {
    height: .2em;
    left: -.4em;
    right: -.4em;
    position: absolute;
}

.pending {
    background: #F8AC59;
}

.running {
    background: #1C84C6;
}

.passed {
    background: #1AB394;
}

.failed {
    background: #ED5565;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">Activity</th>
                <th colspan="4" class="text-center">Jan-17</th>
                <th colspan="4" class="text-center">Feb-17</th>
                <th colspan="4" class="text-center">Mar-17</th>
                <th colspan="4" class="text-center">Apr-17</th>
                <th colspan="4" class="text-center">May-17</th>
                <th colspan="4" class="text-center">June-17</th>
                <th colspan="4" class="text-center">July-17</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">Activity 1</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <div class="task passed" title="Task completed"></div>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">Activity 2</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <div class="task passed" title="Task completed" data-length="10"></div>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <div class="task passed" title="Task completed" data-length="3"></div>
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">Activity 3</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```